# Format cell without directly overwriting the content

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, formatting

I have a VBA Macro that basically generates data and row duplicates based on dates existing in our DB, one of the things that I haven't been able to do is formatting users unique ID, ideally I have to add leading zeroes and removing the `-` char, the longest having id having 10 digits and the shortest 8.

Current data vs What It should show:
[image: Current data vs What It should show]

The problem is when before the data is pasted I run the following excel formula that overwrites the data inside the cell. Leaving the cell as `0` and the formula stored. I know that the formula just gets pasted in the cell and removing the old content.

`=CONCAT(IF(LEN(SUBSTITUTE(G18,"-","") )<9,"00","0"),SUBSTITUTE(G18,"-","") )`

This is a snippet of the macro

```
Private Sub duplicadorLicMed()

Set Application = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

Dim planillaDestino As Worksheet
Set planillaDestino = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count))
planillaDestino.Name = "hojaDest"

Dim planillaFuente As Worksheet
Set planillaFuente = Application.Workbooks.Open("tstfl.xlsm")
Set planillaFuente = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
planillaFuente.Name = "hojaFuente"

Dim filaFuenteUltima As Long
filaFuenteUltima = planillaFuente.Cells(planillaFuente.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

Dim filaIndiceFuente As Long

Dim filaIndiceDestino As Long
filaIndiceDestino = 1 ' salto de lineas y encabezado

Dim fechaInicio As Variant
Dim fechaFin As Variant
Dim fechaIndice As Date

    For filaIndiceFuente = 2 To filaFuenteUltima
    fechaInicio = planillaFuente.Cells(filaIndiceFuente, "L").Value
    fechaFin = planillaFuente.Cells(filaIndiceFuente, "M").Value

    ' VALIDATOR OF DATA

    For fechaIndice = fechaInicio To fechaFin
        filaIndiceDestino = filaIndiceDestino + 1

    ' ROWS GET REPEATED HERE

    Next fechaIndice
Next filaIndiceFuente

'HERE I RUN THE FORMAT FORMULAS

planillaDestino.Range("B2:B" & filaIndiceDestino).Formula = "=CONCAT(YEAR(L2),IF(INT(MONTH(L2))<10,0,""""),MONTH(L2))" ' per pro
planillaDestino.Range("B2:B" & filaIndiceDestino).Formula = "=CONCAT(IF(LEN(SUBSTITUTE(C2,"-","") )<9,"00","0"),SUBSTITUTE(C2,"-","") )" ' digitador rut
planillaDestino.Range("K2:K" & filaIndiceDestino).Formula = "=ABS(DAYS(L2,M2))+1" ' dias totales

MsgBox "PROCESO COMPLETO"

' End If
End Sub
```

So how could I "store" the data while working on it and not losing it's content?

Comment: I cannot tell what you are trying to do.  If you want to keep the value, just put it into a VBA variable.  If you want to keep it in a worksheet cell, write the results to the cell instead of a formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want to use the cell format to make the cell values you provided in your first column (15489651-2) look like your last column (0154896512). As to my knowledge this is not possible as the value "15489651-2" will always be interpreted as a text string and complex string manipulations (like find and replace) are not possible by formatting cells.

Since converting a pure number (154896512) or the string with the leading zero (0154896512) into the format with the hyphen (15489651-2) is very easy by using the cell format "########-#" or the function

```
=TEXT(A1,"########-#")
```

I would recommend checking if a reversed approach is possible. You could change the data to a pure number format which will look the way you desire. Whenever you need it to include the hyphen (for appearance or for other macros) just use the TEXT formula to change it (back) to this format.

Here a general resource when it comes to cell formats: 
https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2016/07/07/custom-excel-number-format/#Repeat-characters

Comment: I ended up using the .Replace function to remove the - , and .NumberFormat for the "00####" hint you gave me, but some users have letters inside so the funtion is unable to transform the value, is there any equivalent for .numberformat but for strings?

Comment: If you want to do this with spreadsheet formulas use the ones for manipulating strings like LEFT, RIGHT or MID. (=LEFT(A1,8)&"-"&RIGHT(A1,1))

Answer (score 0):

First delete "-", make a number, and make the number 10 digits and save the data. Using the format function. You can then format the cell as text and move the data into the cell. This can be done with vba.

```
'HERE I RUN THE FORMAT FORMULAS
Dim rngDB As Range
Dim vDB As Variant, i As Long, r As Long

planillaDestino.Range("B2:B" & filaIndiceDestino).Formula = "=CONCAT(YEAR(L2),IF(INT(MONTH(L2))<10,0,""""),MONTH(L2))" ' per pro
Set rngDB = planillaDestino.Range("B2:B" & filaIndiceDestino)
vDB = rngDB
r = UBound(vDB, 1)
For i = 1 To r
    vDB(i, 1) = Replace(vDB(i, 1), "-", "")
    cnt = 10 - Len(vDB(i, 1))
    s = WorksheetFunction.Rept("0", cnt) 'if letters inside
    'vDB(i, 1) = Format(vDB(i, 1), "0000000000") ' if number
Next i
rngDB.NumberFormatLocal = "@" '<~~ text format
rngDB = vDB
```

**The entire code**

```
Private Sub duplicadorLicMed()

    Set Application = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

    Dim planillaDestino As Worksheet
    Set planillaDestino = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count))
    planillaDestino.Name = "hojaDest"

    Dim planillaFuente As Worksheet
    Set planillaFuente = Application.Workbooks.Open("tstfl.xlsm")
    Set planillaFuente = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    planillaFuente.Name = "hojaFuente"

    Dim filaFuenteUltima As Long
    filaFuenteUltima = planillaFuente.Cells(planillaFuente.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

    Dim filaIndiceFuente As Long

    Dim filaIndiceDestino As Long
    filaIndiceDestino = 1 ' salto de lineas y encabezado

    Dim fechaInicio As Variant
    Dim fechaFin As Variant
    Dim fechaIndice As Date

        For filaIndiceFuente = 2 To filaFuenteUltima
        fechaInicio = planillaFuente.Cells(filaIndiceFuente, "L").Value
        fechaFin = planillaFuente.Cells(filaIndiceFuente, "M").Value

        ' VALIDATOR OF DATA

        For fechaIndice = fechaInicio To fechaFin
            filaIndiceDestino = filaIndiceDestino + 1

        ' ROWS GET REPEATED HERE

        Next fechaIndice
    Next filaIndiceFuente

    'HERE I RUN THE FORMAT FORMULAS
    Dim rngDB As Range
    Dim vDB As Variant, i As Long, r As Long
    Dim cnt As Integer

    planillaDestino.Range("B2:B" & filaIndiceDestino).Formula = "=CONCAT(YEAR(L2),IF(INT(MONTH(L2))<10,0,""""),MONTH(L2))" ' per pro

    Set rngDB = planillaDestino.Range("B2:B" & filaIndiceDestino)
    vDB = rngDB
    r = UBound(vDB, 1)
    For i = 1 To r
        vDB(i, 1) = Replace(vDB(i, 1), "-", "")
        cnt = 10 - Len(vDB(i, 1))
        s = WorksheetFunction.Rept("0", cnt) 'if number & string
        'vDB(i, 1) = Format(vDB(i, 1), "0000000000") ' if number
    Next i
    rngDB.NumberFormatLocal = "@" '<~~ text format
    rngDB = vDB
    'planillaDestino.Range("B2:B" & filaIndiceDestino).Formula = "=CONCAT(IF(LEN(SUBSTITUTE(C2,"-","") )<9,"00","0"),SUBSTITUTE(C2,"-","") )" ' digitador rut
    planillaDestino.Range("K2:K" & filaIndiceDestino).Formula = "=ABS(DAYS(L2,M2))+1" ' dias totales

MsgBox "PROCESO COMPLETO"

' End If
End Sub
```